# Every time I click autofill button it returns "nil" in the field and not the saved string

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I am saving a name in userdefaults and trying to display it in the WkWebView in a certain field using js but every time I click the autofill button it inserts "nil", and not "John Doe" the value that's saved in user defaults. Anyone know why?

ProfileViewController

```
import UIKit


var name: String!




class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        nameField.text = defaults.string(forKey: "nameField")



    }

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
                name = nameField.text


                defaults.set(nameField, forKey: "nameField")

            }


    }
```

ViewController

```
@IBAction func autofill(){
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById(\"cnid\").value = \"\(String(describing: name!))\";",  completionHandler: nil) 
}
```

Comment: where are you assigning the defaults value to name?

Comment: in a different swift file, it saves when i type the value into the text field and close the app out its still there

Comment: so name is a global variable? make sure you are not declaring it again in your current swift file.

Comment: please show us more code and read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: updated code for you

Comment: code is at top @Chris

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
defaults.set(nameField, forKey: "nameField")
```

Use

```
defaults.set(name, forKey: "nameField")
```

Comment: still returns nil